# How to download a file from aws server using SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rhel, amazon-ec2, aws

Environment:
Remote: AWS - RHEL 7.2
Local: Ubuntu 16.04

I SSH into the AWS box directly using a .pem file for authentication, something along the lines of:

```
ssh -i /home/<user>/<path>/<serverkey>.pem ec2-user@ec2-<awsserver>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

What I want to do is simply download a file not owned by the root user, but by another user so the usual scp magic does not readily work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: log in to the server as that user? Copy the file as root to `ec2-user` accessible location and use `scp`?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would look in to why `sftp` or `scp` is not working.

Technically you can do:

```
ssh -t user@host 'cat /path/to/file' > out.file
```

This may **NOT** produce an identical file, but might be good enough for what you want.

For example, my test case transfer produced a file with CRLF (dos) line terminators and the original had LF (unix) - I'm not sure why to be honest. The rest of the file was identical. No binary file was tested either.

The test was performed from Linux to FreeBSD.

Comment: Please elaborate how the file will differ. I'm genuinely interested.

Comment: @phk I added some details to the answer.

Comment: Your solution worked out as follows: `ssh -i /home/<path>/<morepath>/key.pem -t ec2-user@ec2-<server>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'cat /home/ec2-user/file.xml' > /home/<user>/Desktop/out.file`

Worked like a charm. Definitely worth an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ssh — OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)
 scp — secure copy (remote file copy program)
 sftp — secure file transfer program
```

use scp, or sftp. example usage;

```
scp ec2-user@ec2-blabla.com:/home/ec2-user/.bashrc download-bashrc.txt
```

all three work with the ssh daemon.

ps, to attain the file of another user make sure your user has read access to the file (either chmod/chown, or copy the file to your user's home).

Comment: Your solution also worked out real smooth. I shortcut the user rights and copied the file so ec2 could access it and then: `scp -i /home/<path>/<morepath>/key.pem ec2-user@ec2-<server>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/file.xml /home/<user>/Desktop` 

Also worth an upvote. Thank you.